# Event monitoring with watchdogs it is not waiting time for rescan in Python

Tags: python, python-watchdog

I have this simple script that scan an folder looking for excel files, if found then it move to an specific folder. The thing is that I want the scan to happen every 1 minute, I tought that setting `time.sleep(60)` in the while bucle it gonnna works, but it did not. Every time I copy an excel file to the folder that is being scanned it instantly get moved to the folder, I mean it does not wait 1 minute to rescan it is like the `time.sleep` it is not working.

```
import time
import os
import shutil
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

class ExcelHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_created(self, event):
        if event.is_directory:
            return
        
        if event.src_path.endswith('.xlsx') or event.src_path.endswith('.xls'):
            # Destination folder path for moving Excel files
            destination_folder = 'F:/Pedidos'
            
            # Move the file to the destination folder
            file_name = os.path.basename(event.src_path)
            destination_path = os.path.join(destination_folder, file_name)
            shutil.move(event.src_path, destination_path)
            print(f"Moved '{file_name}' to '{destination_folder}'")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    folder_to_watch = 'F:/'
    
    event_handler = ExcelHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path=folder_to_watch, recursive=False)
    
    print(f"Watching folder '{folder_to_watch}' for Excel files...")
    
    observer.start()
    
    try:
        while True:
            print("New scan")
            time.sleep(60)
            print("Scanning folder")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    
    observer.join()
```

I have tried increasing the time to 120 seconds and copying diferents files every 5 seconds, anyways it get moved instantly.